# add space in twilio alphanumeric sender id using ruby

Tags: ruby, twilio

Am using twilio to send sms to my user, now i came to know that we can change from_number to my app name as "Top Expert" using alphanumeric sender id.

This is the name which am using "Top Expert", but while am receiving sms as "TopExpert". Why the spacing is not working, please help to resolve the problem.

```
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new ENV["TWILLIO_ACCOUNT_SID"],
                                   ENV["TWILLIO_AUTH_TOKEN"] 
@client.account.messages.create(
            from: "Top Expert",
            to: "+610412345678",
            body: "Sample testing"
          )
```

Comment: If it's twilio/carrier doing this, then there's nothing you can do about it, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks Mr Sergio Tulentsev

Comment: I don't think SMS sender_id can contain spaces, most providers seem to say 11 characters, alphanumeric. Even though the Twillio docs seem to indicate otherwise. Best to contact them ask.

Comment: You may use any combination of 1 to 11 letters, A-Z and numbers, 0-9. Both lowercase and uppercase characters are supported as well as spaces. 1 letter and no more than 11 alphanumeric characters may be used. This the content provided by twilio.

Comment: yep, the docs are probably wrong.

Comment: Look at other SMS providers, none seem to show examples of spaces in the sender ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here. As per comments above and documentation [here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181348-Getting-started-with-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID), I can confirm that you can only use characters that are A-Za-z or 0-9, so a space won't work.

The docs read:

> **What characters can I use as the sender ID?**
>
> You may use any combination of 1 to 11 letters, A-Z and numbers, 0-9.
>   Both lowercase and uppercase characters are supported as well as
>   spaces. 1 letter and no more than 11 alphanumeric characters may be
>   used.

That is because carriers won't accept anything that is outside of that scope.

Hope this helps you

Comment: *@Marcos* this is what they have mentioned in their docs(Both lowercase and uppercase characters are supported as well as spaces.) They have mentioned it will support spaces. Please advise.